# How to fix "clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am on macOS, using visual studio code

I created a simple program that simply prompts the user to enter in their name and validates it. It is a multiple cpp program. I can run the code fine using the terminal. However, I want to be able to simply press the run code button on Visual Studio Code instead of having to recompile by command every time.

My Gym folder has files Person.cpp Person.h and main2.cpp. It also has .vscode with c_cpp_properties and settings.json

The error that prints in the terminal when I run the code using the button is:

```
quincythai@Quincys-MacBook-Air .vscode % cd "/Users/quincythai/Documents/Gym/" &
& g++ main2.cpp -o main2 && "/Users/quincythai/Documents/Gym/"main2
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "Person::askUserInfo()", referenced from:
      _main in main2-23f400.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

## main2.cpp

```
#include "Person.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Person p;
    p.askUserInfo();
    
}
```

## Person.h

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Person
{
    private:
        string name;
        int age;
        int height;
        int weight;
        char gender;
        int heightFeet;
        int heightInches;

        bool isValidName(string name);

    public:
        void setName(string n);
        void setAge(int a);
        void setHeightFeet(int hF);
        void setHeightInches(int hI);
        void setWeight(int w);
        void setGender(char g);

        string getName();
        int getAge();
        string getHeight();
        int getWeight();
        char getGender();

        void askUserInfo();
        void displayUserInfo();
        void getLiftingSkill();
};
```

## Person.cpp

```
 #include "Person.h"
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 using namespace std;


bool Person::isValidName(string name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)name.length(); i++)
    {
        if (!isalpha(name[i]))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void Person::setName(string n)
{
    while (!isValidName(n))
    {
        cout << "Enter a valid name. ";
        getline(cin, n);
    }
    name = n;
}

void Person::setAge(int a)
{
    while (a < 0)
    {
        cout << "Invalid. Value must be greater than 0. " << "\n";
    }
    age = a;
}
        
void Person::setHeightFeet(int hF)
{
    while (hF < 0)
    {
        cout << "Invalid. Value must be greater than 0" << "\n";
    }
    heightFeet = hF;

}

void Person::setHeightInches(int hI)
{
    while (hI < 0 && hI > 12)
    {
        cout << "Invalid. Value must be greater than 0 and less than 12" << "\n";
    }
    heightFeet = hI;
}
        
void Person::setWeight(int w)
{
    while (w < 0)
    {
        cout << "Invalid. Enter a weight above 0. " << "\n";
    }
    weight = w;
}

void Person::setGender(char g)
{
    while (g != 'm' || g != 'M' || g != 'f' || g != 'F')
    {
        cout << "Invalid. Enter in m/f. " << "\n";
    }
    gender = g;
}

int Person::getAge()
{
    return age;
}

string Person::getHeight()
{
    string height = to_string(heightFeet) + "'" + to_string(heightInches) + "\"";
    return height;
}
        
int Person::getWeight()
{
    return weight;
}
        
char Person::getGender()
{
    return gender;
}

void Person::askUserInfo()
{
    cout << "Name: ";
    getline(cin, name);
    setName(name);
}
//void displayUserInfo();
//void getLiftingSkill()
```

Comment: Person.cpp was not compiled. This is the default behavior of VSCode to build only the active file. This part of the VSCode documentation explains this: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac#_modifying-tasksjson)

Comment: `>> g++ main2.cpp Person.cpp -o main2`

Comment: @drescherjm I modified tasks and added the command to build all files. Still same error. All the cpps are in the same folder.

Comment: @dmedine I'm trying to find a way to run it without typing in the terminal

Comment: It will be the same error if the build command did not include Person.cpp.